# How to create multiple models in one controller action -- Phoenix Framework?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to be able to create a User and an Email model when a client invokes the UserController's create method. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Is the User connected to the Email via belongs_to and has_one | has_many?
Can you show an example incoming params map?
Do you need this to be a transaction that either fully works or fails?

Answer (score 0):

For inserts, you can directly populate the associations and just pass the data to `Repo.insert!`.

There is a good discussion of this feature in chapter 7 of [Whats new in Ecto 2.1](http://pages.plataformatec.com.br/ebook-whats-new-in-ecto-2-0) "Improved associations and factories"

```
Repo.insert! %User{
  name: params["name"],
  email: %Email{
    address: params["email_address"]
  }
}
```